# One Content type multiple usages of that content type, reusable background field?

Tags: entities, blocks, media

As the title says. I have ran into a weird issue. I need to find a way to reuse my content type but allow myself to edit the background of that content type. So eventually i would have a lot of instances of the same content type but the field background image would be reused through out  with different images. Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanking you in advance